# Does IwUI work with multi-touch?

Tags: marmalade

Is it possible to set up 3 CIwButton widgets (let's say, "left", "right", "fire") and be able to use "left"/"right" while holding down the 'fire' button? Or would I need to write my own button class to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. If you are defining event handling methods in your UI and making a `IWUISLOT` for every button, every button will have it's own touch event. I don't think you'll need any separate button class for this.